# JAX-WS multiple endpoints in sun-jaxws.xml

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

Just started using JAX-WS. I created 2 test web services in the one WAR file as follows....

```
package com.djs;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService()
public class AddTwoInts {

    public int performAdd(int firstNum, int secondNum) {
        return firstNum + secondNum;
    }
}
```

And.....

```
package com.djs;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService()
public class SayHello {

    public String sayHello(String inwards) {
        return "Hello " + inwards;
    }
}
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jaxws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jaxws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is the sun-jaxws.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime' version='2.0'>  
    <endpoint name='performAdd' implementation='com.djs.AddTwoInts' url-pattern='/AddTwoInts' />
    <endpoint name='sayHello' implementation='com.djs.SayHello' url-pattern='/SayHello' />
</endpoints>
```

I deploy into Tomcat 7 and use `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/AddTwoInts?wsdl` to get the WSDL for AddTwoInts OK.... But when I execute `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/SayHello?wsdl` I get a 404 page not found error....

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

Dave,

I guess you are missing the servlet-mapping for the two end points you have.

Add the following to your web.xml and try again. Let me know if this solve the problem.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddTwoInts</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddTwoInts</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddTwoInts</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SayHello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SayHello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SayHello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: That fixed it, Thankyou....... Out of interest, why can't I point both endpoints at the same servlet ?? I thought the JAXWS servlet used the endpoint mappings in sun-jaxws to figure out which endpoint class to call. Therefore if I point all URL's to the one servlet, it should be able to figure out what to do....

Comment: I guess it is possible to map your multiple endpoints to one servlet, however your "sun-jaxws" should have all enpoints defined separately.

Try this:
`**web.xml:**
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SomeName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SomeName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

**sun-jaxws.xml:**

No change.`

Comment: A single `servlet-mapping` can have one `servlet-name` and multiple `url-pattern` entries, which would be what you'd want to do if a wildcard incorrectly matched non-web service resources in the same container (static resources, JSF or JSP, etc.).  No need to specify the `servlet` twice.

Answer (score 2):

You want the web.xml to reference only one servlet, at urlMapping /:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>services</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
      </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>services</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Then, include multiple endpoints at the full desired path in sun-jaxws.xml:

```
<endpoint name='performAdd' implementation='com.djs.AddTwoInts' url-pattern='/AddTwoInts' />
<endpoint name='sayHello' implementation='com.djs.SayHello' url-pattern='/couldhavemore/SayHello' />
```

Note the "couldhavemore" in there... you can add to the relevant path in the sun-jaxws.xml file to get the full desired path. I've gotten a single service to work with a web.xml entry of something other than /, but then you need a web.xml entry for every service. It seems to get multiple to work you need to use / and then put the full path in sun-jaxws.xml.