# Soap - Support for same function-name in different classes?

Tags: soap, wsdl, jax-ws, apache-axis

I'm currently tasked with reworking our webservice-layer for various servers.

On **Websphere** (8.5.5.9 - uses axis2 afaik) or **Tomcat** (7 using com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt) the services won't work if a `@WebService` class has a `@WebMethod` with the same name as another class - on **JBoss** (EAP 6.2) it works just fine.

Does anyone know a workaround/reason for this problem (preferably one that *doesn't* involve renaming the methods)?

### Example Code

```
// example class one
@WebService(name = "ServiceOne", targetNamespace = "http://serviceone.namespace/", serviceName = "ServiceOne")
public class ServiceOne {

  @WebMethod
  public ServiceOneResponse echo(final ServiceOneRequest request) {
    String echo = request.getPayload();

    ServiceOneResponse resp = new ServiceOneResponse();
    resp.setPayload("ServiceOne echo: " + echo);

    return resp;
  }
}

// example class two
@WebService(name = "ServiceTwo", targetNamespace = "http://ServiceTwo.namespace/", serviceName = "ServiceTwo")
public class ServiceTwo {

  @WebMethod
  public ServiceTwoResponse echo(final ServiceTwoRequest request) {
    String echo = request.getPayload();

    ServiceTwoResponse resp = new ServiceTwoResponse();
    resp.setPayload("ServiceTwo echo: " + echo);

    return resp;
  }
}

// request class one
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://serviceone.request/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "http://serviceone.request/")
public class ServiceOneRequest {

  String payload;

  public String getPayload() {
    return payload;
  }

  public void setPayload(final String payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
  }
}

// request class two
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://servicetwo.request/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "http://servicetwo.request/")
public class ServiceTwoRequest {

  String payload;

  public String getPayload() {
    return payload;
  }

  public void setPayload(final String payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
  }
}
```

### Edit 1

On *Websphere* the services are auto-detect, on *Tomcat* they are bound to seperate endpoints using the *sun-jaxws.xml*.

The behavior I'm seeing is:

- Deployment works (no error, no warning)
- Both services are reachable (wsdl gets published)
- One of the services will report an error when used (for example using SoapUI)
- Other service will work as intended

### Edit 2

*sun-jaxws.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
    version="2.0">
    <endpoint name="ServiceOne"
        implementation="com.dsw.services.soap.ServiceOne"
        url-pattern="/soap/one" />
    <endpoint name="ServiceTwo"
        implementation="com.dsw.services.soap.ServiceTwo"
        url-pattern="/soap/two"/>
</endpoints>
```

Soap-Fault (using SoapUI):

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>argument type mismatch</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

...and the matching Tomcat stacktrace:

```
Apr 13, 2016 10:30:47 AM com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
SEVERE: argument type mismatch
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.run(Fiber.java:813)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.start(Fiber.java:420)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.processAsync(WSEndpointImpl.java:368)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:398)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.invokeAsync(HttpAdapter.java:734)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:212)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:197)
  at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:81)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you get a deployment error or is only one of the two services available?  It seems like bad behavior from the application server. Do you declare the web services in web.xml (verify they have separate servlet mappings) or do you use auto-detect?

Comment: Hi Willem, I edited the question. On JBoss EAP & IBM WS the services are auto-detect, on Tomcat I use the sun-jaxws.xml to bind the endpoints (seperate adresses yes).

Comment: Can you paste the sun-jaxws.xml and SOAP fault returned? You could also try to add @SchemaValidation to your web services, to see which schema is taken for input validation.

Comment: Sure thing, see my edit #2, added the matching stack-trace as the soap-fault is a bit... empty of information. Also tried @SchemaValidation but I see not only no difference, I also see no mention that it would be validated?

Comment: Could this be the issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172463/jax-ws-multiple-endpoints-in-sun-jaxws-xml

Comment: Had a look at the linked question/answers but no luck, behavior exactly as before. I guess renaming the methods is the way to go...

Comment: Please check this. I think it's pretty close to your issue. I faced the same problem and tries a lot to fix it, but no success. I changed a SOAPBinding to RPC and was able to start on tomcat and even can do calls to second class webmethods, but webparams look like arg0,arg1,arg2 now for some reason. https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-738